# Adding a LIKE Finder on a Localized column in Liferay Service Builder

Tags: liferay

I have a column that have been set to Localized="true", is there a way to add a finder that only matches LIKE on specific locale?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think it would be possible: localized columns are stored as xml strings in db, and I haven't found any example of a search like this in Liferay source. Have you considered using the index? It would be way easier to do a LIKE query for a localized field.

Answer (score -1):

You can use xPath (if you use a db engine that supports it, for example postgresql)